# Adding TestCaseSteps to TestCases using Rally Rest for Java

Tags: java, json, rest, rally

I am creating a function that updates Test Cases, and have been stumped for a while with this situation. I am trying to figure out a way to add given steps to test cases and it has not been working. However, the other fields can be modified. Here is an example of that

```
JsonObject testCase = new JsonObject();
testCase.addProperty("Method", "Automated");

JsonArray steps = new JsonArray();
JsonObject stepOne = new JsonObject();
JsonObject stepTwo = new JsonObject();

stepOne.addProperty("Input", "Push Button");
stepOne.addProperty("ExpectedResult", "Light Show");
stepTwo.addProperty("Input", "5 syllables");
stepTwo.addProperty("ExpectedResult, "Joke");

testCase.addProperty("Steps", steps);

UpdateRequest updatedCase = new UpdateRequest();
rest.update(ref, updatedCase);
```

This will change the Method of the requested Test Case to Automated, but no steps will be added. There is no error thrown so I'm wondering what I did wrong here. Do I have to create the steps before I link the steps and case together? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In general in Rally's WSAPI is is usually easier to set the association from the child back to the parent.  In this case rather than trying to add items to the Steps array of the TestCase instead simply create your TestCaseStep objects and specify the TestCase's _ref as the TestCase value to link them.

```
JsonObject stepOne = new JsonObject();

stepOne.addProperty("Input", "Push Button");
stepOne.addProperty("ExpectedResult", "Light Show");
stepOne.addProperty("TestCase", "/testcase/12345"); //specify test case object id in place of 12345

CreateRequest createStepRequest = new CreateRequest("testcasestep", stepOne);
rest.create(createStepRequest);
```